# Changing globally defined list as locally

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a question about the python variables. As you see below, I have defined with **L** a list
and  with **I** an integer variable after that, i have added new number to list inside function as locally.I can use the changed list outside the function as globally; on the other hand same situation is not for the integer variable.
Can someone help me please ? What is the difference?
PS:I know that ,I use integer variable inside the function as local variable because of that, it doesn't change on global. but why not a list variable?

```
L=[] 
I=5
def change_var(I,L):
    I=10
    L.append(12)
    print('Inside function I',I)
    print('Inside function L',L)
    return I,L
change_var(I,L)
print('Outside function I',I)
print('Outside function L',L)
```

**Result**

````
>>>Inside function I 10
>>>Inside function L [12]
>>>Outside function I 5
>>>Outside function L [12]```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a variable gets affected a value anywhere inside the body of a function (as in `variable = ...`), then it is considered to be local, unless you explicitely declare it `global` in this function.

You treat `I` and `L` very differently:

- You assign a value to `I` in `I = 10`, so it is considered local, and so a different variable from the other, global `I`. The changes you make to it can't be reflected on the other, global `I`. If you wanted to act on the global `I`, you should have declared `global I` at the start of your function.
- You don't assign anything to `L`, you just mutate the unique, already existing global list.

Comment: Thanks for your response, if i correctly understand you, a list can not be assigned  to a variable?

Comment: Of course it can. See the excellent https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for more details on how things work in Python.

Comment: thanks, i got it properly at first situation i mutate the list  by adding new number with L.append(12), but if i assign new  list  inside function like   L=[12],  the list also will behave  local  variable!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the name of the variables you are using inside the function, since you are creating new variables for `I` and `L` when inside the function, if you don't. In my example, I have changed them to lowercase(`i` and `l`). Also, when you put a number/variable inside the function parenthesis, it sets the variables inside the function to that number/variable, rather than putting that number inside the variable. So, when you put `change_var(I,L)`, it effectively running the function, but putting the lines `i=I` and `l=L` at the start, rather than replacing all `i`s with `I`s. To fix this, you will have to make `I` global when inside the function, so it affects code outside of the function, and then make `I` equal `i`.
The full code would be

```
L=[]
I=5
def change_var(i,l):
    i=10
    l.append(12)
    print('Inside function I',i)
    print('Inside function L',l)
    global I
    I=i
    return i,l
change_var(I,L)
print('Outside function I',I)
print('Outside function L',L)
```

The code should work, but I'm sorry if my explanation didn't make any sense - I'm still quite new to answering on Stack Overflow.